# Material angular autocomplete keeps giving me error

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to make this [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) work but somehow it is not working for me. It keeps giving me error
[image]

servers.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})

export class User {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}

export class ServersComponent {

  myControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    new User('Mary'),
    new User('Shelley'),
    new User('Igor')
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  filter(name: string): User[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }
}
```

I have imported both `User` class and `ServersComponent` in `app.module.ts`.

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import "hammerjs";

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
import { ServersComponent, User } from './servers/servers.component';
import { MyFormComponent } from './my-form/my-form.component';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    MyFormComponent,
    User,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However if i use this [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter) it is working fine.

Can you let me know what I am doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in this line,

```
import { ServersComponent, User } from './servers/servers.component';
```

Usually you can have only one component from a select/component.  Remove User from the same.

To add more on the issue, you should not export two classes from same component. change your component as,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServersComponent {

  myControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    new User('Mary'),
    new User('Shelley'),
    new User('Igor')
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  filter(name: string): User[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives same error as in screenshot. It doesn't change anything. Previously I had it without User and I thought I missed to add User so I added it but the error exist.

Comment: @Santosh i have added more details in the answer now

Comment: what about ` new User('Mary'),` this object is not defined right ?

Comment: you can define that separately inside a .ts file and import

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome :)